# AVPlayer empties buffer when app is in background

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm using `AVPlayer` to play HLS streams. While playing, the `AVPlayer` buffer's. If I put the app in background, `AVPlayer` pauses, which is fine. That's what I want. But the problem is that the `AVPlayer` buffered data is lost. So the user has to wait until `AVPlayer` buffers again before it can start playing.

Is there a way to stop `AVPlayer` from dumping the buffered data when put in background? I need it to be able to immediately resume when coming back to foreground. Thanks.

Comment: Mihai, did you succeed to solved the issue

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did not find a way to stop AVPlayer from doing that.

Comment: I am facing same issue but not always. Only for few assets I am facing this issue.